# Navigating down the DOM in console

Tags: javascript

Cheeky on the fly JS question.

I have an element whose value I would like to get. The h4 element is nested under a div of class pricing_numbers. How would I drill down further in the DOM to get the value of H4 that is nested under this element?

See the picture attached. I'd like to get the value $59.99

[image]

I got this far. But how to drill down to what I need?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pricing_numbers")
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".pricing_numbers > h4").textContent` - `querySelector` has slightly better browser support than `getElementsByClassName`. But if you wanted to still use it, you could do `document.getElementsByClassName("pricing_numbers")[0].getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].textContent`. Use this for compatibility: http://caniuse.com/, and info on `textContent`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Comment: thanks for the useful info. Will go with querySelector since it seems to be more robust

Comment: Oh one more, if you're still there? If the element in question is a table data point, what then? Tried the following:
document.querySelector('.product-price')
document.querySelector('.product-price').textContent (gave "productprice" not the number I was seeking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.pricing_numbers > h4').innerHTML.
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Accepting shortly. Sorry for the cheeky question I know it's not really SO standard